# Translation of labels

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, internationalization, multilingual

I already have one application running (in English language).

I want to translate those application text to some native langauges with my program.
It it possible to change it?

Comment: Is English not a native language?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at I18N (internationalization) resources related to VB.net. Typically when a program is designed to be used amongst many different cultures/languages the interfaces are designed to use resources rather than hard coding the text. This allows for the interface language to be seperated from the logic. It also makes the job easier for the translators. They get handed the resource files, and they return the resource file with all the correct translations.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  The part of the library you'll be interested in is [System.Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx).  Beyond that, it will depend on the platform ([ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx), [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28VS.80%29.aspx), etc.).